# getJSON function get data from url on localhost only

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, getjson

I use below function to get the Continent Code from the api which works fine on localhost but fail in live environment which is website

```
$.getJSON('//www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?jsoncallback=?', function (data) {
  // console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data.geoplugin_continentCode));
});
```

Warning which i see in Console is

> Loading failed for the  with source
>   “https://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?jsoncallback=jQuery16407901144106031991_1537089290623&_=1537089292750”.

I am not sure why it fails on website https://www.example.com

could SSL version some problem as i am not sure as i tried it on fiddle & it works fine http://jsfiddle.net/om8ahkp3/

**UPDATE**

Since problem was due to crossdomain issue which as this api used a different url for ssl version. i was not able to use this ssl version as it was not free.

So ended up using another api which had free option also limited to 50k request on monthly basis.

```
$.ajax({
                url: 'https://api.ipgeolocation.io/ipgeo?fields=is_eu& excludes=ip&apiKey=YOURKEY',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (json) {
                    console.log("json.is_eu " + json.is_eu);
                }
            });
```

Comment: At first look, I can't find this code in your example.com. If you forgot to add then you should add this code to your website.

Comment: Are you running an ad-blocker by any chance that has an exception for `localhost` but not for your live site?

Comment: My code is exactly what is show in example one in yellow is the warning showing in Console window. and i have no ad blockers either. after removing `?jsoncallback=?` this from url it is now giving me cross browser warning  `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed)`

Comment: Why would you remove the `jsoncallback`?

Comment: To see if it works or generates different error?

Comment: The ipgeolocation.io is now only 30k limit per month..(free option)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the whole problem?
**You want to access to a third site (`crossDomain`).** So, That site decides that you can access to it, or not. When a site provides a service (similar `geo` service that you have used it), it determines which part of it's services are free.

In your case, if your source site's protocol is `http` (like as `localhost`) and dest site (service provider site) is `http` too, you can access to this geo service with your above code (because this third site allows this now). But if you want to access to this service from a `https` site (I think you are trying this now) the `geoPlugin` don't allow you easily or free!

In this cases, the destination sites, provide another `url`s and define user levels (to getting money for special services.).

In act, if your dest site was for yourself too(which it is not in this case), you could add needed access to specific referer sites, but now...

I look at its site to be sure.  You must use this url in this case:

https://ssl.geoplugin.net/json.gp?k=yourAPICode

But this is not all of things! What is `k` in above url? This site [writes](https://www.geoplugin.com/premium): 
**"For SSL access, an API Key is required to offset certificate prices and costs €12 per year."**

I don't know, but if you need it, you should search for free plugins (if exists) or buy it.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out also later on while investigating and warning was due to crossdomain issue. unfortunately ssl version is not free. so ended up using different API which is support 50K monthly request for free with ssl support. will add that to my question also.. I will mark you solution as correct as it address issue

Comment: You're welcome :) I'm glad the problem solved. And thanks for introducing that service in your original post.